# Illegal instruction in random.py when building yocto dunfell

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, yocto, cpython

I'm in the process of upgrading my Yocto build from sumo to dunfell but I get an error in package `python3-setuptools-native` (v45.2.0-r0) which states that it has hit an `Illegal instruction`. My yocto tmp and sstate-cache directories are both new (i.e. no sumo builds lingering).

This is the content of the `log.do_compile` file after failing.

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed.
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Execution of '/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.2778959' failed with exit code 1:
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

As a way of debugging the issue and get a stack trace I opened up a devshell and started running python with faulthandler enabled. I basically picked the first few lines from `setup.py` and ran them manually one by one and it failed on `import setuptools`. The backtrace points to line 69 of `random.py` in the python install (i.e. not in python3-setuptools-native package).

Line 69 of random.py

```
RECIP_BPF = 2**-BPF
```

Fault handler output

```
mans@localhost:~/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/setuptools-45.2.0$ python3 -q -X faulthandler
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> import setuptools
Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction

Current thread 0x00007f79ddfa0740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 69 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/email/utils.py", line 28 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/email/_policybase.py", line 9 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/email/feedparser.py", line 27 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/email/parser.py", line 12 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/setuptools-45.2.0/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/setuptools-45.2.0/setuptools/version.py", line 1 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/mans/oe-build/am335x-board/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/python3-setuptools-native/45.2.0-r0/setuptools-45.2.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 17 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Anyone seen something similar when building yocto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case (Ubuntu 20 to compile Yocto 3.0), @tim's solution does not work. Instead, I changed this file:

`poky/meta/conf/distro/include/yocto-uninative.inc`

to:

```
UNINATIVE_URL ?= "http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/2.10/"
UNINATIVE_CHECKSUM[aarch64] ?= "645e5c50b2b48aabb8b10f783a9f94b4b7c5ddc7cfceb5386d43b86d30253202"
UNINATIVE_CHECKSUM[i686] ?= "233e09b5ff30e15341232a0c16fa8448ff31dccb8f3f3e2ad3948cdac8c4a598"
UNINATIVE_CHECKSUM[x86_64] ?= "04333677f81990ce2cf55c3bc256cd84a66085d18fc95ccddfab8581e4aec014"
```

which is copied from a yocto patch:

https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?h=dunfell&id=cdda267645506b2471a1085b42de3cdfa238d8d5

Comment: This was fixed on the dunfell branch on the link posted by Felix above, so accepting his answer as it is the most correct one.

Comment: If you use git for poky you can do `git cherry-pick cdda267645506b2471a1085b42de3cdfa238d8d5` to apply the patch to your version. That worked for me in zeus.

Answer (score 1):

this is a toolchain bug in glibc-2.32 that made it into the uninative toolchain: https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14215

as a workaround you can disable uninative, e.g. by `INHERIT_remove = "uninative"` in your configuration